# Align column vertically with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 `columns` in a `row`. The first and second are wider, and the third is narrower and needs to include only a buy button and the price. This is how it looks at this point:

[image]

I need to align the right most `column` to the middle of the others. tried a bunch of combinations suggested around here but none seem to work. Here's my `css class`:

```
.vertical-align {
   flex-direction: row;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   float: none;
}
```

EDIT: I'm adding the entire `row`:

```
<div class="row bottom-buffer15 searchresultbg">                      

    <!-- product image column -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3" style="border:1px solid red">
      <a href='#{product.itemUrl}' target="_blank"><img src='#{product.thumbnailUrl}' /></a> <br/>                  
    </div>

    <!-- product details column -->
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6" style="border:1px solid red">
      <a href='#{product.itemUrl}' target="_blank">#{searchResults.getTruncatedTitle(product)}</a> <br/><br/>       
      <h:panelGroup rendered="#{searchResults.isEbay(product)}">
      Sale Type: #{product.saleType} <br/>
      Bids: #{product.numberOfBids} <br/>
      Time: #{product.timeLeft} <br/>
   </h:panelGroup>

  <!-- site logo -->
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{searchResults.isEbay(product)}">
    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="ebaylogo.jpg" width="40" />
  </h:panelGroup>

  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{searchResults.isAmazon(product)}">
    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="amazonlogo.jpg" width="40" />  &nbsp;
  </h:panelGroup>

  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{searchResults.isEtsy(product)}">
    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="etsylogo.jpg" width="30" />  &nbsp;
  </h:panelGroup>

</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 vertical-align" style="border:1px solid red;">
  <a href='#{product.itemUrl}' target="_blank">
    <h:graphicImage name="images/buybutton.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="display: inline-block; margin-left:0px; margin-bottom:-0px;"/>                        
  </a>

    <br/> #{product.currentPrice}
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT2: `JFiddle` linke: http://jsfiddle.net/pc1Lwu0b/

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle for this? Why are you using flex-direction with inline-block?

Comment: Hi @ManojKumar, removing either of flex-direction or inline-block doesn't help. WHat do you mean by a "working fiddle"? This is a JSF project so it won't be easy to upload.

Comment: I edited the question to add the entire bootstrap row.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ You can copy paste the code there and give us a link to play with the code and of course help you. Better if you can give us an output that is same as the image. No flex-direction is not related to inline-block, it is related with flex. So I said that :)

Comment: I added a jfiddle linke to the question: http://jsfiddle.net/pc1Lwu0b/ Thanks!

Comment: Ok, it seems your fiddle doesn't contain all the elements. Can you say if this will be of the same height everytime as now? I can tell you a solution if that is the case.

Comment: Yes, they would always be the same height. It does also need to be responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a margin to your third column because you have a fixed height. This solution will work.

```
.vertical-align {
   margin-top: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: You may not need the margin when you are viewing it in mobile, so wrap this code inside @media (min-width: 768px) { } Adjust the width accordingly.

I am not clear of the code you are using in the fiddle, hence I had to make a hack out of it :)